Firewall is blocking incoming responses in Google Cloud Function
My Google Cloud Function is connected with a Static IP Address. It is making API calls to Adobe Reactor API and Jira API. Jira API requires a static IP address. Adobe Reactor API doesn't necessarily need a static IP address.
When the Cloud Function runs, it sends requests to Adobe Reactor API and waits for the response for around 2 minutes. After 2 minutes, the Cloud Function throws ETIMEOUT error. Please check the Cloud Function logs below for a detailed error message.
2024-09-05 04:50:07.486 IST renewal-daily   mvzuva5wgfwq    Function execution started
2024-09-05 04:50:07.911 IST renewal-daily   mvzuva5wgfwq    (0). Adobe Launch secrets fetched: 11:20:07 PM
2024-09-05 04:50:08.217 IST renewal-daily   mvzuva5wgfwq    (1). Adobe Launch & Google Gmail access_token created
2024-09-05 04:50:08.217 IST renewal-daily   mvzuva5wgfwq    (2). Adobe Launch client created
2024-09-05 04:50:08.220 IST renewal-daily   mvzuva5wgfwq    (3). Iteration through property started: ZP6_IL
2024-09-05 04:50:14.065 IST renewal-daily   mvzuva5wgfwq    (4). All media rules fetched: ZP6_IL
2024-09-05 04:50:23.549 IST renewal-daily   mvzuva5wgfwq    (5). All rules about to expire in 5 days filtered: ZP6_IL
2024-09-05 04:50:34.793 IST renewal-daily   mvzuva5wgfwq    (5.5). All rules already expired filtered: ZP6_IL
2024-09-05 04:52:50.082 IST renewal-daily   mvzuva5wgfwq    Trace
2024-09-05 04:52:50.082 IST renewal-daily   mvzuva5wgfwq    at exports.renewTags (/workspace/index.js:157:13)
2024-09-05 04:52:50.082 IST renewal-daily   mvzuva5wgfwq    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
2024-09-05 04:52:51.083 IST renewal-daily   mvzuva5wgfwq    Error: request to https://reactor.adobe.io/rules/RLf123123123123123123/rule_components failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 34.233.244.146:443
2024-09-05 04:52:51.757 IST renewal-daily   mvzuva5wgfwq    ERROR email sent.
2024-09-05 04:52:51.759 IST renewal-daily   mvzuva5wgfwq    Function execution took 164272 ms, finished with status code: 200

I believe that the since I am using a Static IP address, the Firewall is blocking the response from coming back. The firewall settings in GCP are as shown below.

Can anyone please help resolve the ETIMEOUT error? Please check below points,

Does the Firewall settings need any enhancements?
The IP Address shown in the error message should be whitelisted somewhere?
If the Firewall settings are correct, do I need to fix any error anywhere else?


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78953895/firewall-is-blocking-incoming-responses-in-google-cloud-function

As per your latest comment in stack overflow ,it seems like the issue is with the VPC connector rather than your code or API itself. Ensure that private google access is enabled for your VPC as it allows your VPC resources to access google APIs without needing an external IP address.
Also you can try to configure Cloud NAT gateway, if your cloud function is using a VPC and requires internet access.This allows your resources within the VPC to access the internet and receive responses from external API’s.

And regarding the timeout issue ensure that your cloud function has an appropriate timeout setting that accommodates for any network latency. Also refer to this documentation.For timeout issues in the cloud functions  you can refer to this.

Did you have time to check my answer? I am looking forward to your response to understand whether the provided information has helped you in resolving the issue. If not, I am happy to assist further.
